# Setup a qemu KVM (Proxmox) with 8 cores but 16 threads

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, proxmox

The goal is to give one VM max. 8 virtual cores, but still have 16 threads in this VM. Reason for this is SQL Licensing because it is licensed per Core, so that on a physical machine with 8 hardware cores, you would only have to license 8 cores and would have 16 threads, but in a VM for having 16 threads you would need 16 vCores what means double licensing costs.

Answer (score 1):

Proxmox does not expose threads per core.

Do performance testing in an SMT scenario with a hypervisor that supports it. Such as oVirt or kvm directly. Possibly a performance boost, but it will be nowhere near double.

Comment: But isn't proxmox using KVM, so shouldn't it be possible to do it?

Comment: What the kvm backend can do does not matter if the UI and API are not aware of the relevant options. Try writing the kvm command line yourself as a proof of concept.